# Stacked NavigationPage with a FlyoutPage in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

Is there a way to get stacked NavigationPage with a FlyoutPage in .NET MAUI.

I have FlyoutItems on the left and then on the right I have the content/page of respective flyout item.

But if the content/page has a button to take to another page it opens a whole new page without the flyout and no back button to go back.

I wanted to stack the new page on top of current page and see a back button  (similar to what you will see when doing a Shell navigate) while keeping the flyout on the left.

This Flyout is not part of the MainPage and instead is part of a Settings page I have.

Is this even possible? or just a limitation?

Comment: May I know on what platform you are targeting?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT windows

Comment: I think it's possible, you can refer to my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the `Button` is in `Page2` and when clicking it, it'll navigate to `Page1`. You can use the code below to navigate to `Page1`.

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
```

In your [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-8.0) code behind:

```
public FlyoutPageDemo()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    flyoutMenuPage.collectionView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
}

void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as FlyoutPageItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        var myNewpage = ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));

        // get the navigation page
        var myPage = (ContentPage)((NavigationPage)Detail).CurrentPage;
        myPage.Navigation.PushAsync(myNewpage);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What I meant was suppose there is a button on page 2 which takes to another sub page which is not one of the flyoutitem page. Will it still work the same with the above code? or is it a requirement for it to be a part of the flyoutitem.

Comment: @user1111 Yes, it should be a part of the flyoutitem. Otherwise, the flyout may disappear.

Comment: that’s the original question I had. I want to have the sub page without It being a flout menu. As it is a subpage of another page and not something which I want to be a page of its own

Comment: @user1111 In your `FlyoutPage`, you can set [Layout behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-8.0#layout-behavior) as `FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover "`  which will have the sub page without a float menu and then use `await Navigation.PushAsync(new YourSubPage());` to navigate.

Comment: I didn't have to set up the FlyoutLayoutBheviour. It worked regardless. I'll probably have to set up a custom back button but that looks easy. Cheers.