# How to get responsive layout with a flyout like UI .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, telerik, maui

I have this UI design where I have a flyout/docklayout on the left side for list of settings and then on the right side the content of selected settings is shown.

On Desktop I would like the UI to be as above where the content of selected settings or actual pages and not Views.

On Mobile device I want to have the list of settings that covers the whole page (no flyout) which takes to their respective settings page.

I have tried using a FlyoutPage and telerik controls for DockLayout and NavigationView.

Sub issue: [Stacked NavigationPage with a FlyoutPage in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790079/stacked-navigationpage-with-a-flyoutpage-in-net-maui)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to MAUI, but I found that you can conditionally use Flyout on the Desktop, and bottom tab menu on the mobile - so you can create separate UI for different devices. Maybe you can use this mechanism to apply your requirements. Look at `FlyoutBehavior="{OnIdiom Phone=Disabled, Default=Locked}"`. Link to [full example with the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/apps-weathertwentyone/).

```
<Shell 
    FlyoutWidth="68" FlyoutBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background_Mid}"
    FlyoutBehavior="{OnIdiom Phone=Disabled, Default=Locked}">

    <Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="68">
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image Source="tab_settings.png"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       WidthRequest="40"
                       HeightRequest="40"
                />

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>

    

    <!-- Desktop/Tablet-->
    <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Style="{StaticResource HomeFlyout}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:HomePage}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Favorites" Style="{StaticResource FavFlyout}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:FavoritesPage}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Map" Style="{StaticResource MapFlyout}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:MapPage}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Route="settings" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:SettingsPage}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <!-- Phone -->
    <TabBar x:Name="PhoneTabs">
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="tab_home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:HomePage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Favorites" Icon="tab_favorites.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:FavoritesPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Map" Icon="tab_map.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:MapPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Settings" Icon="tab_settings.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:SettingsPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>



    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid WidthRequest="44" HeightRequest="68"
                  ColumnDefinitions="44" RowDefinitions="68">
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"                               
                       HeightRequest="38"
                       WidthRequest="38"
                       />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
</Shell>
```